# Ambiguous regex escape \num

Tags: c#, regex

According to [this reference](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet), there are two escape sequences `\n` and `\num` where `n` is an octal number, and `num` is a positive integer. The former is an escape value that gets converted to a character, and the latter is a back-reference.

Isn't that ambiguous? How can the regex tell them apart? When does it decide to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's ambiguous.. but if you look through MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx) it's explained how it is solved:

> Note the ambiguity between octal escape codes (such as \16) and \number backreferences that use the same notation. This ambiguity is resolved as follows:
>
> The expressions \1 through \9 are always interpreted as backreferences, and not as octal codes.
>
> If the first digit of a multidigit expression is 8 or 9 (such as \80 or \91), the expression as interpreted as a literal.
>
> Expressions from \10 and greater are considered backreferences if there is a backreference corresponding to that number; otherwise, they are interpreted as octal codes.
>
> If a regular expression contains a backreference to an undefined group number, a parsing error occurs, and the regular expression engine throws an ArgumentException.

Really a silly choice to have the same syntax for both elements, since you can generate weird bugs if you don't follow this precise reference to how the ambiguity is solved.

Answer (score 4):

The rules of disambiguation are described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx:

---

Note the ambiguity between octal escape codes (such as `\16`) and `\number` backreferences that use the same notation. This ambiguity is resolved as follows:

- The expressions `\1` through `\9` are always interpreted as backreferences, and not as octal codes.
- If the first digit of a multidigit expression is 8 or 9 (such as `\80` or `\91`), the expression as interpreted as a literal.
- Expressions from `\10` and greater are considered backreferences if there is a backreference corresponding to that number; otherwise, they are interpreted as octal codes.
- If a regular expression contains a backreference to an undefined group number, a parsing error occurs, and the regular expression engine throws an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ambiguous. I will venture that the ambiguity is resolved in favour of interpreting it as backreferences. If an octal number is truly desired, it can always be prefixed with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it tries to match a backreference and if it fails, it attempts a octal number match.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I thought so too, but apparently that isn't exactly true. `\7`, for example, will always be treated as a back-reference, regardless if it exists or not (if I'm reading this correctly).